# Structure from motion using sparse bundle adjustment

Tags: opencv, 3d, structure-from-motion

I don't have calibrated camera,I have taken stereoscopic images from web.

I wanted to create structure from motion of the images,So I was lookin at Tsai's algorithm and Sparse Bundle adjustment.

But,I got struck while finding camera parameters.What mathamtical background will be reuqired to understand these concepts?

The 'Multiple view Geometry' is not that much helping.

Comment: I know basic Epipolar gemometry but I am unable to write code on Sparse Bundle adjustment.

Comment: http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/sba/ for codes, docs, AND LECTURES NOTES

Comment: What exactly do you have? Only single image pairs? Do you have initial camera parameters, like focal length or something? Do you have images showing the calibration patterns?

Comment: I dont have any parameters. I don't have any calibration patterns in my image. I just have stereoscopic images which are captured from a equal height.